# json_encode with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE not working properly

Tags: php, json

I am trying to manipulate a JSON file with PHP and am encountering the problem, that the function

```
$json = json_encode($cd, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

is not working properly.

Code:

```
    <?php 
    $contents = file_get_contents('file.json');
    $ut=  utf8_encode($contents);
    $cd = json_decode($ut, true);        
    $cd['File'][0]['Name']="AnotherName"; 
    $json = json_encode($cd, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    file_put_contents('general.json', $json);
    ?>
```

The manipulating is working, however there are some ä,ö,ü and / symbols, which are changed to Ã¤... and / in the output file. Is there any way to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `file.json` contains actual valid JSON encoded in UTF-8, the only issue you have is that you're messing up your encoding by using `utf8_encode` on it. `utf8_encode` converts ***from ISO-8859-1*** to UTF-8, which is unnecessary since your input is not ISO-8859-1. The problem has nothing to do with the `json_encode` function.

Consider reading [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).